# Android Google Maps Utils Cluster Manager marker above clusters

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps Utils library for clustering markers.
I'm adding most of markers to cluster manager. The rest I'm adding to map (I don't want them to be clustered with others). My problem is that clusters are drawn above standard markers and cover them. Is there any way to change drawing order i.e. first clusters and markers above them?

Here's part of my code:

```
    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getActivity(), map);
    clusterManager.setRenderer(new MyObjectRenderer(getActivity(), map, clusterManager));
    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);

    for (MyObject object : list) {
        clusterManager.addItem(object);
    }

    clusterManager.cluster();

    for (MyOtherObject object : otherList) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(object.getLatLng()).title(object.getName()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar scenario: I was adding several locations to my ClusterManager and I needed a marker with the user position on top of all the other markers.

This worked for me:

Add user marker to map with zIndex to 1000 to ensure that it will be placed on top.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude())).zIndex(1000);
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Add markers to cluster manager.

```
for (MyObject object : objects) {
     mClusterManager.addItem(object);   
}
mClusterManager.cluster();
```